# Late Javascript file loading causing event registration failure

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which will register a handler to window.load event. But the issue here is that function containing javascript file loads by a content management system and by the time the file gets loaded in to the page, the window.load is getting completed and as a result the handler is not at all getting registered and invoked.

Could anyone please suggest something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use AMD- require js, wherein you can specify dependencies to use as given below. Only once the js is loaded, you can attach some event as given below

```
require(['someUtils'], function(someUtils){
                        someUtils.attachHandler(element);
                })
```

or you can delay attaching the handler by invoking the function using `setTimeout()`

or if you are using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});
```

Comment: The issue is with the time difference between the file loading and window.load event triggering. Can you please suggest a way to make sure the handler gets registered before window loading completes?

Comment: If you are not using Require js, you can delay your loading as given below https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/   Hope this helps